# Jenkins: Passing metrics between jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to store metrics of a build in Jenkins, that it is both visible on the build page, and that allows other jobs to later access these metrics and take action based on them?

In my particular case I am running a matrix configuration job. It is performing 25 or so builds. Each build result is archived as an artifact. Each build result has a metric indicating its quality. It is currently stored in a file among the artifacts.

A second job needs to take the build artifact with the best quality metric. Currently it is copying the artifacts from all 25 builds for evaluation, and deletes everything but the best one. But this takes time as each build artifact is about 100MB.
Additionally, it would be nice if the build quality metric was published visually per build in Jenkins.

My current best idea is to only copy the metric report file artifact from each build first, evaluate them, and then somehow copy the complete artifacts only from the best build. Perhaps using the groovy plugin or something similar.
But I am hoping there is a more integrated solution which also makes the metrics of each build more easily viewable on the build page.

The "Plot plugin" is very nice for visualising metrics, but it does not seem to make the metrics available to other jobs?

(Background for those interested: The matrix build job is performing FPGA Place&Route iterations distributed over a build farm, and the quality metric is the achieved timing margin for each iteration)

EDIT

For clarification, below is a image where I have tried to illustrate the current setup. All jobs run on Jenkins slaves. No jobs run on the Jenkins master, it only holds the artifacts.
As can be seen, a total of 2x25x100MB = 5 Gigabyte of data is copied between Jenkins slaves and the Jenkins master. This takes a significant amount of time.
As little as only 2x100MB would need to be copied if the metrics could be evaluated earlier.
[image: Current setup]

Comment: why don't you publish only the best quality metrics instead of all of them? Then you will not need to copy all of them to another job.

Comment: Having the matrix job evaluate and publish the best metric? Yes, that would also work. But I am not aware of such a function in Jenkins?

Comment: then the question is - how are you determining best metrics?

Comment: The metric parameter is available in a report file in the workspace och each build. The highest is the best. In fact, the most ideal solution to my problem would be if the matrix job only archives the artifact with the best metric. But is this even remotely possible?

Comment: I don't know how your metrics looks like and how are you determining the best one, but can you realize the main statements of the metrics just as some strings/numbers? According to them you can pass all of them to the job, which is combining them and checks which build artifact should it download (e.g. with the help of groovy script OR https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin or https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin)

Comment: The matrix job has 25 configurations. All 25 configurations/builds run in parallel on different Jenkins slave nodes. Each will produce about 100MB of files in its own workspace. One of the files in each builds workspace is called "metric.txt" containing a string representation of a decimal number. Examples: "-0.123", "1.236", "0.001". Highest is best. The "Conditional build step" or "Run condition" plugins can probably be used, but in order to use them, the values from all the metric.txt files must somehow be made available in Jenkins variables of some sort. And that is the main problem here.

Comment: Got it fully now. A very nice task for a brain, will try to do something tomorrow, because for now everything I could imagine is Groovy script usage with parametres passing to the master job.